# Div not centering within parent div with margin auto

Tags: html, css

I know I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I've tried   `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;`, and the inner div is not centering horizontally within my parent div?

```css
.row-fluid-wrapper.row-depth-1.row-number-3 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: 28px;
  margin-left: .2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
}

.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.914893614%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-3 ">
  <div class="row-fluid ">
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget ">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span>
  <div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-text">
              <p>Col 1</p>
              <p>Text.</p>
          </div>
  </div>
  </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 2</p>
<p>Text.</p>
        </div>
</div>
</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 3</p>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
</div>
</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the blue divs are more left aligned than being in the middle.

Comment: "_blue divs are more left aligned_" Because you put `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the style `float: left` and make display property as `display: inline-block` for the class `.row-fluid [class*="span"]`, as follows. Please find the [working example here](https://codepen.io/Kartm/pen/ddZaWN).

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
    min-height: 28px;
    margin-left: .2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if understood correctly this would do:

On the css for : `.row-fluid [class*="span"]`

**Add:** `display: inline-block;`

**Remove:** `float: left;` , `margin-left: .2%;` , `display: block;`

This will result in fully centered `divs.`

```css
.row-fluid-wrapper.row-depth-1.row-number-3 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
 /* display: block;*/
 display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
  min-height: 28px;
 /* margin-left: .2%;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
}

.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.914893614%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-3 ">
  <div class="row-fluid ">
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget ">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span>
  <div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-text">
              <p>Col 1</p>
              <p>Text.</p>
          </div>
  </div>
  </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 2</p>
<p>Text.</p>
        </div>
</div>
</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <span><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 3</p>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
</div>
</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using css properties correctly at all...

**1**...applying `margin:0 auto` with `display:block` in `row-fluid` is aligning it center but there is `width:100%` so no need to use `margin:0 auto` here.

**2**...then you have applied `margin: 0 auto` in `span4` with `flaot:left`, which is again wrong.

**3**...why are you using `display:block` with `width:100%` in `div`....divs are by default `display:block` with `width:100%`...

**4**...also using `margin-left:.2%` in `span4` div will not center visually as it will also add margin to the last div also...apply `margin:0 .1%`

**5**...also no need to set `min-height` and `height` both in the `spa4` div

What you need to do is just remove the `float:left` from the `span4` class and set it as `display:inline-block`...your `.span4` div will align center as you have used `text-align:center` in the parent div `.row-fluid-wrapper`

*Note: Here I have applied the `font-size:0` to the parent class to remove the white space between the `inline-block` div and then again set the `font-size:initial` to the inner div*

Here is the minimized version of your code

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.row-fluid-wrapper.row-depth-1.row-number-3 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: initial;
}

.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.914893614%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-3 ">
  <div class="row-fluid ">
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget ">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 1</p>
            <p>Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 2</p>
            <p>Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget">
      <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
        <div class="clearfix cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-text">
            <p>Col 3</p>
            <p>Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```